# Java 8 forEach over multiple IntStreams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
    IntStream.range(0, width).forEach(x1 -> {
        IntStream.range(0, height).forEach(y1 -> {
            IntStream.rangeClosed(x1-1, x1+1).forEach(x2 -> {
                IntStream.rangeClosed(y1-1, y1+1).forEach(y2 -> {
                    if ((x1 != x2 || y1 != y2) && getNode(x2, y2) != null){
                        getNode(x1, y1).registerObserverAtNeighbor(getNode(x2, y2));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Is there a way to write the above using fewer nested statements? It's basically "for each node from (0,0) to (width,height) register observer at nodes from (x-1,y-1) to (x+1,y+1), but not at self".

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you can replace nested loops with a `Stream` using `flatMap`. This requires that you choose an element type capable of holding the information equivalent to the loop variables, if you need it. In your case, it’s the two values for `x` and `y`. It would simplify the code if your `Node` class holds these information as you can easily iterate over nodes rather than `int` values then. Since you didn’t specify the capabilities of your `Node` class, here is an example which uses a `long[]` of size two to hold the points:

```
IntStream.range(0, width).boxed()
  .flatMap(x->IntStream.range(0, height).mapToObj(y->new int[]{ x, y }))
  .forEach(p1 -> {
    Consumer<Node> register=getNode(p1[0], p1[1])::registerObserverAtNeighbor;
    IntStream.rangeClosed(p1[0]-1, p1[0]+1).boxed()
    .flatMap(x->IntStream.rangeClosed(p1[1]-1, p1[1]+1).mapToObj(y->new int[]{ x,y }))
      .filter(p2 -> (p1[0] != p2[0] || p1[1] != p2[1]))
      .map(point -> getNode(point[0], point[1]))
      .filter(node -> node != null)
      .forEach(register);
  });
```

It still simplifies the innermost code by moving code to the outside, where possible, e.g. the `getNode` calls. You can also simplify the code by putting the repeated task of creating a `Stream` over points for an area into a method:

```
static Stream<int[]> area(int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1) {
  return IntStream.range(x0, x1).boxed()
  .flatMap(x->IntStream.range(y0, y1).mapToObj(y->new int[]{ x, y }));
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
area(0, width, 0, height).forEach(p1 -> {
    Consumer<Node> register=getNode(p1[0], p1[1])::registerObserverAtNeighbor;
    area(p1[0]-1, p1[0]+2, p1[1]-1, p1[1]+2)
      .filter(p2 -> (p1[0] != p2[0] || p1[1] != p2[1]))
      .map(point -> getNode(point[0], point[1]))
      .filter(node -> node != null)
      .forEach(register);
  });
```

It still could be easier if you have/use a dedicated point class or if the node class holds the point information (and has a comparison method for it, in the best case).

Answer (score 1):

What you have is basically 4 nested loops. It makes sense because you are iterating over two dimensions of a matrix, and then, for each node, you iterate over a small matrix that consists of its neighbourgs.

Something like this.

```
0000000
0---000
0-X-000
0---000
0000000
```

I guess you could use a recursive function just for the syntax, although no benefit really.

```
iterateLambdas(0, width, 0, height, 1);

public static void iterateLambdas(
        int start1,
        int end1,
        int start2,
        int end2,
        int depth) {
    IntStream.range(start1, end1).forEach(x1 -> {
        IntStream.range(start2, end2).forEach(y1 -> {
                    if (depth != 0) {
                          iterateLambdas(x1 - 1, x1 + 2, y1 - 1, y1 + 2, depth - 1);
                    } else {
                          // Current node : (start1 + 1), (start2 + 1)
                          // Current neighbour : x1, y1);
                          // Your logic here
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you operate on nodes I suggest to create streams of nodes in the first place. Please note that I'm making some assumptions about the nodes.

```
getNodes(0, width - 1, 0, height - 1).forEach(node -> {
  getNodes(node.getX() - 1, node.getX() + 1, node.getY() - 1, node.getY() + 1)
    .filter(neighbor -> !neighbor.equals(node))
    .forEach(neighbor -> node.registerObserverAtNeighbor(neighbor));
});
```

Creating a stream using your approach:

```
private static Stream<Node> getNodes(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(x1, x2)
    .mapToObj(x -> (Stream<Node>)IntStream.rangeClosed(y1, y2).mapToObj(y -> getNode(x, y)))
    .flatMap(nodes -> nodes)
    .filter(node -> node != null);
}
```